# Query database, explode snapshot and populate dropdown with unique snapshot

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column named snapshot in the database

snapshot

US,96,97,89

89

US,56,58

SS,TEST

when i explode the above table using delimeter ,(Comma) then i will get the output as

US  //duplicate elements

96

97

89  //duplicate elements

89

US  //duplicate elements

56

58

SS

TEST

i have wrritten the code as

```
$sqll = "select distinct unique_id,MAX(snapshot) from unique Group By snapshot order by snapshot ASC"; $q = mysql_query($sqll) or die(mysql_error()); ?>
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php 
                while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) 
                {?>
<?php 
                    $e = explode(",", $r[0]);
                    foreach($e as $r)
                    {?>
<option value="<?php echo $r; ?>"><?php echo $r; ?>
</option>
<?php }?>
<?php>
```

Any best queries please update !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
i am not able to get

Comment: Not very clear... need more on what's repeating and what you need to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$sqll = "select distinct unique_id,MAX(snapshot) from unique Group By snapshot order by snapshot ASC"; $q = mysql_query($sqll) or die(mysql_error()); ?>
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php 
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
      $e = explode(",", $r[0]);
      $e = array_unique($e); //removes redundant array values
      foreach($e as $r=>$val)
      {
        echo "<option value='".$val."'>".$val."</option>";
      }
    }
?>
```